# Error installing package RandomFields from Package Archive in R

Tags: r, installation, tar, archive, cran

I'm trying to install the package georob, which is no longer on CRAN. In order to install georob, I need first to install the package RandomFields which is no longer on CRAN neither. Therefore, I downloaded the file RandomFields_3.3.tar.gz from CRAN Archive and then tried to install the package RandomFields with the following command in R:

```
install.packages(pkgs = "C:/documents/RandomFields_3.3.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:257: brownresnick.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RandomFields'
```

My installations are as follows:
Windows 10 Home, 64-bit
R version 4.2.0
R Studio 2022.07.2+576
Rtools42 for windows

Any idea how I can install georob and/or RandomFields?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try with the latest version: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RandomFields/RandomFields_3.3.14.tar.gz

Comment: there should  be some more error output somewhere, which would be very useful ...

Comment: @ Phil: Thank you for your help. I was able to install the version you sent without any problems. (I've noticed now that I chose the version at the very bottom of the list in CRAN archive which unfortunately is not the latest version.) For the sake of completeness, here are the further steps I followed for installing georob: after having installed the package RandomFields, install the package constrainedKriging (I installed version 0.2.4), then install the package georob (I installed version 0.3-14). Package georob seems to work correctly now on my computer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: Thank you for your answer. As I wrote in the previous comment, I erroneously tried to install an old version of the package RandomFields what lead to the error message explained in my question. I can not rule out that I have overlooked other error messages.

Comment: @ Phil: would you please post your answer so that I can mark your answer as "accepted"?